# How to show full object with VSCode Code Runner in the OUTPUT section?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, vscode-code-runner

When running JS code via Code Runner, my output is often abbreviated to [Object] and I am unable to see the full result of running a JS function. Is there a setting that allows full console logging of the full output rather than just abbreviating a lot of it into [Object]? The image below is my console log output of a linked list based toy problem with the output being the linked list as an object. On a similar note, is there a more preferred method to run code for these toy problem / leetcode style problems in VSCode or is Code Runner sufficient? [image]

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
  console.log(JSON.stringify(value, null, 2));
```